# Как разделить строку на слоги?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как разделить строку на слоги, с одним но? Например есть строка `heuumoogxieietwvoognptaooemkzayeiokxxiusioiau'pclskjafwbudzkxoao` ее нужно разделить на `['heuu', 'moo', 'gxieie', 'twvoo', 'gnptaooe', 'mkzayeio', 'kxxiu', 'sioiau', 'pclskja', 'fwbu', 'dzkxoao']`.

Т.е. **если после согласной идет гласная и потом опять согласная, то это первый слог**, **если же после гласной идет опять гласная, то нужно ее так же нужно добавить к этому слогу**.

Каким методом можно это сделать без импорта других библиотек и чтобы функция работала максимально быстро с длинными строками? И как это сделать?

Comment: Проще всего - регуляркой. Чтобы быстрее работало - идти циклом по строке.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то каждый слог у вас начинается с согласной буквы, так что вы можете просто в цикле пройти по строке и проверять, что если данная буква согласная, а прошлая гласная, то нужно начать новый слог.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать циклы. Вот код:

```
string = input()
parts = []
latestLetter = ""
nowLetter = ""
vowels = "aeiouyAEIOUY"
for i in range(len(string)):
    nowLetter = string[i]
    if i == 0:
        parts.append(nowLetter)
    elif latestLetter in vowels and nowLetter not in vowels:
        parts.append(nowLetter)
    else:
        parts[len(parts) - 1] += nowLetter
    latestLetter = nowLetter
print(parts)
```